# VS2017 NuGet: Dependencies not install automatically

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-explorer

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2017. When I install any package, nuget manager not installs dependencies. For example, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite has 2 dependencies and I must install it manually.

Is it normal behavior? As I remember in the past nuget manager did dependencies installation automatically.

Comment: The package manager will show the dependencies even if they are not explicitly declared in nuspec (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element) - as they are added automaticalky. In my experience, in those cases the dependencies are not always resolved.

Answer (score 1):

> VS2017 NuGet: Dependencies not install automatically

Your package should be managed as `packagereference`. You could edit your project file `.csproj` to check it.

Unlike `packages.config`, **PackageReference lists only those NuGet packages you directly installed in the project**. As a result, the NuGet Package Manager UI and the project file aren't cluttered with down-level dependencies.

Besides, the dependencies info included in the `project.assets.json` in the  `obj` folder. You do not need to install the dependencies manually.

You can check the document [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with the community version. It was resolved by switching from the Community to the Professional. For both the 2019 and 2022 versions.